# Json deserialization with key value mapped object

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to deserialize a json string to Java object. Here is my json string.

```
{
  "header": {
    "transactionId": "12345",
    "application": "testApp"
  },
  "items": {
    "item": [
      {
        "attributes": {
          "attribute": [
            {
              "key": "accountType",
              "value": "TYPE1"
            },
            {
              "key": "accountId",
              "value": "123"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "attribute": [
            {
              "key": "userType",
              "value": "TYPE2"
            },
            {
              "key": "userId",
              "value": "321"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I want to deserialize this json to Java classes that shown as below.

```java
public class Response {
    private Header header;
    private List<Object> items;

    //getters and setters
}
public class Header {
    private String transactionId;
    private String application;

    //getters and setters
}
public class Account {
    private String accountType;
    private String accountId;

    //getters and setters
}
public class User {
    private String userType;
    private String userId;

    //getters and setters
}
```

How can I deserialize by using jackson or objectmapper etc.? The main problem is the field names are in the attribute object and the value of 'key' field. Is it possible to find the right field on Java object by using value of the 'key' field and to set the right value with the value of the 'value' field?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to transform the JSON structure before converting to POJO.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(yourJsonString);
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(header," +
    "    items: items.item@" +
    "          .attributes.attribute" +
    "          .map(key::value)" +
    "          .mergeObjects()" +
    "   )");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "header" : {
    "transactionId" : "12345",
    "application" : "testApp"
  },
  "items" : [ {
    "accountType" : "TYPE1",
    "accountId" : "123"
  }, {
    "userType" : "TYPE2",
    "userId" : "321"
  } ]
}
```